# How do I install Laravel 5 on windows 8.1 after installing composer?

Tags: laravel-5

I am stuck installing Laravel 5 on Windows 8.1.

After installing composer on my PC, I followed this link: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#install-laravel but I'm not able to understand the last section of "install laravel 5 via laravel installer"...specially this line:

> Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system.

Comment: Usually the composer installer for windows does this by itself, just try to call `laravel new ...` and you'll see if it works pretty fast ;)

Comment: Yes it does...but I am not able to understand the line......make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory ...........line....can you please help me out for this

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29

Answer (score 4):

1. After executing this command `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`
2. Type `Environment Variables` in  Windows search, Click on `Edit the System Environment variables` -> `Environment Variables`.
3. Find the `path` field and click on Edit. At the end, type a `;` and paste the below path:

   `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

The above path is a common installation path for composer. Replace username with yours.